# Angular 8 wait for rest api response in subscribe

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, angular8

In component.ts i have this method which is calling api and working with response. I am getting an empty array as it is not waiting at subscribe

```
disp(): String[] {
    let scores: String[] = [];
    this.assessmentService.getPrograms().subscribe(
      (res: AssessmentResponse[]) => {
        res.map(
          function (t) {
            const body = `{id: ${t.id}, name: "${t.name}"}`;
            scores.push(body);
          })
        return scores;
      },
      (err: HttpErrorResponse) => {
        if (err.error instanceof Error) {
          console.log("Client-side error occured.");
        } else {
          console.log("Server-side error occured.");
        }
      });
    console.log("returned");
    return scores;
  }
```

I want to store the array return from disp

```
 programList$ = observableOf(this.disp);
```

And then i am using programList$ for setting values for options, I am posting a small piece of code as it has multiple tabs

```
 tabs: TabType[] = [
    {
      label: 'Assign Program',
      fields: [
        {
          fieldGroupClassName: 'display-flex',
          fieldGroup: [
            {
              className: 'flex-1',
              key: 'campaign',
              type: 'select',
              templateOptions: {
                label: 'Campaign',
                placeholder: 'Select Campaign',
                // description: 'Campaign Name',
                required: true,
                options: this.programList$,
```

this my service call

```
 public  getPrograms(): Observable<AssessmentResponse[]> {

         return this.http.get(this.endpoint,this.headers.httpOptions)
         .pipe(map((data: EmbeddedAssessmentsResponse) => data._embedded.programs));          
    }
```

PS: I am new to angular and typescript, any help is appreciated.

Comment: Your code doesnt make sens if you want to wait on the subscribe to be called. Where is disp() being called?

Comment: updated from where disp is called

Answer (score 0):

If your `programList$` is an Observable, your `disp()` method should return an Observable:
`programList$ = this.disp();`

```js
disp(): Observable<String[]> {
  return this.assessmentService.getPrograms().pipe(
    map((res: AssessmentResponse[]) => {
        return res.map(t => `{id: ${t.id}, name: "${t.name}"}`);
      }),
    catchError((err: HttpErrorResponse) => {
        if (err.error instanceof Error) {
          console.log("Client-side error occured.");
        } else {
          console.log("Server-side error occured.");
        }
        return of([]);
      });
  );
```

Answer (score 0):

As the subscribe callback is executed asynchronously, your array is going to be empty if you try to read it before the callback is executed.

Just create a property `programList` in your component and assign the data returned from the API when the subscribe callback is executed, and then call a function to create the `tabs` array. You can try something like this:

```
programList: string[];
tabs: TabType[];

disp(): void {
    this.assessmentService.getPrograms().subscribe(
      (res: AssessmentResponse[]) => {
        let scores: String[] = [];
        res.map(
          function (t) {
            const body = `{id: ${t.id}, name: "${t.name}"}`;
            scores.push(body);
          })
        this.programList = scores;
        this.createTabsArray();
      },
      (err: HttpErrorResponse) => {
        if (err.error instanceof Error) {
          console.log("Client-side error occured.");
        } else {
          console.log("Server-side error occured.");
        }
      });
}

createTabsArray(): void {
    this.tabs = [
    {
      label: 'Assign Program',
      fields: [
        {
          fieldGroupClassName: 'display-flex',
          fieldGroup: [
            {
              className: 'flex-1',
              key: 'campaign',
              type: 'select',
              templateOptions: {
                label: 'Campaign',
                placeholder: 'Select Campaign',
                // description: 'Campaign Name',
                required: true,
                options: this.programList,
                ...
                ...
                }
            ...
            ...
            }]
}
```